# How to save image in byte[] to sql server(varbinary(max)) windows

Tags: image, winforms

I'm getting error 
implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed use the convert function

i have used varbinary(max) datatype in ms sql server for storing image and converted image to byte[] and trying to save the image.

```
        public bool InsertProd(PRODUCT_CAT crse)
        {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            bool success;
                query.Append("INSERT INTO PRODUCT_CATEGORY (PROD_CATE_ID,PROD_IMAGE) VALUES"('" + crse.Id + "',','" +crse.Image+ "')");


            success = dbObj.ExecuteQuery(query.ToString());
            return success;
        }
```

```
 public class PRODUCT_CAT
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Imge { get; set; }
         public PRODUCT_CAT(int id,byte[] image)
        {
            Id = id;
        Imge = image;

        }
    }
```

updated  code

```
public int InsertProd(PRODUCT_CAT crse)
        {
            int success;
            string ins = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT_CATEGORY (PROD_CATE_ID,PROD_IMAGE) VALUES" +
              " (@id, @img)";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ins, con);
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", crse.Id));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", crse.Imge));

            success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return success;
        }
```

[now byte[] is saved like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifvgF.png)

Comment: Your *Image* is a byte array by you're trying to pass a string. Build the query using `Parameters.Add()` to add a byte array specifying the correct data type explicitly. Your query string definition, as of now, would not even compile (you can also see this here in the code formatting: everything after `query.Append()` is considered part of the string).

Comment: As a suggestion, don't name `Image` a property that is not an Image: it's misleading. Maybe something like `imageBytes`.

Comment: @Jimi  would you please show me an example how to implement this using Parameters.Add()

Comment: @Jimi I have done this using Parameters.Add() , but byte is not saved . In database it is as this word <binary data>. i have attached updated code and image by editing the question.

Comment: You forgot to set the `@Id` parameter (you need to `.Add()` all the Parameters you specify in the query). But, shouldn't `crse` contain both `Id` and `Image` properties? What are you passing as the extra `byte[] n` argument? Isn't `crse.Image` the byte array you need?

Comment: @Jimi i have dited my code but result is same . yes crse.Imge contains byte[5477] value.

Comment: That's not the way you specify a parameter. See the Docs: [SqlCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters): `cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.VarBinary, crse.Imge.Length).Value = crse.Imge;`. No idea what's in `crse.Imge`. No idea what that `Id` represents. I hope is not a primary/foreign key. No idea if it can contain duplicates. Search SO about this matter, you'll find thousands of questions.